# Bottom overflow issue when I click the emoji button and emojis are not displayed

Tags: flutter, dart, overflow, emoji, mobile-application

I am developing a chatapp using flutter,nodejs and socket.io. The issue is in my chatting page, when i click the emoji button, the bottom overflow error occurs also the emojis are not displayed. I used emoji_picker_flutter 1.6.3 package. I published this project in my GitHub repository -> [text](https://github.com/AmarMe/chat_app). GO to folder lib->screens->person_screen.dart. This file contains the emoji picker.

1. [image: tap into a person chat]
2. [image: click the emoji button]
3. [image: Bottom overlow issue occured]

I tried some solutions such as wrapping columns with the Singlechildscrollview, expanded widgets. But still not solved and its almost a day gone. So I want to have the emojis to be displayed and when i click again that should hide.

Comment: Please, share the code.

Comment: (https://github.com/AmarMe/chat_app/tree/main/lib/screens)

Answer (score 0):

You can try by wrpping your content with `SingleChildScrollView` or `Expanded`, or you can make your widget as responsive for every deivce.

You can make as responsive by using `MediaQuery`, look at bellow example,

```
 SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // Your other chat content

            // Example for using MediaQuery for emoji picker
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3, // Adjust this as needed
              child: YourEmojiPickerWidget(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhanusha Dilshan for you response. But I solved by commenting a line in Personscreen.dart file ->body->Align ..Here I commented the container with height:70 ..then the issue solved